# Search by SKU in Magento not working properly

Tags: catalogsearch, sku, special-character, elasticsearch2

Over 3000 of our SKUs contain special characters such as "-", "/", "&". The problem is when we try to search regular SKU (e.g. ABC123) on the front end it returns the correct result; however when we try to search the SKU having special characters (e.g. ABC-123), it returns multiple results, and sometimes the original SKU doesn't even appear on first 5 pages. How can we resolve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Add Below code in below file.

> /vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/SearchAdapter/Query/Builder/Match.php

Add below line Number 86 replace condition

```
if ($matchKey != 'match_phrase_prefix') {
    $matchQuery['operator'] = "AND";
 }
```

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Elasticsearch treats the "-" character as word delimiter. You could tell Elasticsearch to ignore (strip) the "-" when indexing the SKU. The user can still enter the character, but Elasticsearch will treat it as being left out during the search process.

The Elasticsearch docs should give you guidance to configure a tokenizer to achieve this, e.g. check edge_ngram tokenizer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not a coder, I did another trick searching for SKUs with special characters, the way this is achieved is to use the meta_keyword field to populate the SKU replacing special characters with spaces.  For example, SKU "ABC-123" would have “ABC 123” in the meta_keyword field.  When the user enters “ABC-123” in the search bar the proper SKU is the first item returned in the search results (if sorted by “Relevance”).